# When uninstall component package isn't uninstalled

Tags: joomla-4

Hello my joomla extension is done with a package whith contains the compenent, the library, the plugins, the medias. I have an auto-uninstall feature into my component, but when use it at the end Joomla! said that the package is still here . That's is the code that i use in a controller of my component :

```
$installer = new MyExtensionModelInstall;
$installer->uninstall();
$installer->deleteTables('myextension_');

$installer = new \Joomla\CMS\Installer\Installer;
$component = ComponentHelper::getComponent('com_myextension');
$installer->uninstall('component', $component->id);

if (File::exists(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/manifests/packages/pkg_myextension.xml'))
{
    File::delete(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/manifests/packages/pkg_myextension.xml');
}

$this->setRedirect('index.php?option=com_installer');
```

So, how to uninstall too the extension package ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

In your `pkg_myextension.xml` you need to declare, as a minimum, an `<uninstall>` SQL file to remove the associated data from the Joomla database. It could be something as simple as below, depending on your database structure.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__yourcomponent_table1`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `#__yourcomponent_table2`;

DELETE FROM `#__content_types` WHERE (type_alias LIKE 'com_yourcomponent.%');
```

You probably ought to review [the docs here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file) too.